# Simulating activity death in Android

Tags: android, serialization, android-activity, lifetime

We know that when the system runs out of resources, an activity in background serializes its state and gets killed by the OS. When we resume it, the OS recovers the activity state by savedInstanceState passed to onCreate method. Considering we are responsible for handling what is going to be serialized/recovered, I'd like to have my activity killed in order to test the code I created for recovering. How can I achieve that? Forcing the application to be killed through the applications menu doesn't help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rotate your device (or emulator).  Android saves, destroys, and re-creates the activity in the new orientation.

Comment: Rotation is not good enough, because some stuff are still in memory, like the activity's intent. When Android kills the activity and rebuilds it, it also rebuilds the intent. This means that if you change the intent (save state in it), upon rotation, you will have the latest change but in runtime the intent will loose the new change.

Answer (score 0):

Download a task manager that kills the process in a less destructive way than "Force stop" in "Manage applications" settings. Example: GO task manager.

The task manager will kill the app (and the debug) but somehow not the activity stack (don't know why).

When you'll relaunch the app again, onCreate will be invoked with the last saved bundle/state.

The **disadvantage** of this solution, compared to Darrell's, is that you cannot debug it.

The **advantage** of this solution, compared to Darrell's, is that it is more close to real life scenario.

Answer (score -1):

You can kill it from Eclipse also. 
Go to the Android view. YOu should see the list of processes in the Devices tab.
Click on your process and then click the little "STOP" button.
Instant death! 
FYI you can also attach the debugger this way by clicking on the little green bug

Comment: Thank you, but doing this I'll be killing the entire process. I just want to kill an activity.

Comment: Oh.. yep sorry. Only thing I can think about is the 'bad behavior' options in the 'dev tools' app. It's in the app drawer of the emulator. You can generate ANRs and crash some threads.